# Handling Cron Job

Tags: java, linux, unix, cron, cron-task

My Application takes files from SFTP and start processing it.I have a cron job which is set to 5 minutes.Suppose The file arrived at SFTP,The pull operation take the file and start processing records inside it .Howerver processing time is more so after 5 minutes cronjob again pulls the second file and finds the first file to be processing and halts.

How to handle this situation .
Please Help.

Comment: if you can't change your cron job not to halt, then your process should move the file somewhere else before processing, I think

Comment: You should have some kind of flags to handle these situations. You can for example create a fake empty file in `/tmp/myscript` that gets removes once the first cronjob finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a cron job for applications if you are not absolutely sure that they will never run longer than the interval between their runs. Use sleep!

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
    get_files_from_sftp
    process_files
    sleep 5m
done
```

@Leo's suggestion may not work, because we do not have enough details about your application, it may not be capable of running multiple times in parallel. But give it a try.

@fedorqui's suggestion is also good. Use `mktemp` to create unique temporary files, or put a `pid` file in `/var/run/*`.